Why doesnt Dagger @IntoMap & @ClassKey make any sense in Kotlin
im investigating the use of dagger to create and inject Set(s) into Maps with the kotlin code shown below
the first thing that doesnt make any sense is using kotlin @ClassKey(ErikTenHag::class),
even though the ClassKey annotation is implemented as follows:-
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@MapKey
public @interface ClassKey {
  Class<?> value();
}

e.g. using java.lang.Class NOT KClass when i try setting @ClassKey(ErikTenHag::class.java) i get this error message

Next, when i make the injection site for the Map as follows:-
@JvmSuppressWildcards
data class FootballLeague @Inject constructor(val teamMap: Map<@JvmSuppressWildcards KClass<*>, Set<Player>>) {

i get compile time error
[Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<?>,java.util.Set<Player>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

When I make the injection site
@JvmSuppressWildcards
data class FootballLeague @Inject constructor(val teamMap: Map<@JvmSuppressWildcards Class<*>, Set<Player>>) {

my code compiles fine and works as required.
is it my expectations that dagger 2 should make some sort of sense or am i missing something?
i do not like having to use "*" in the class definition, i would much rather set a concrete interface or class however i cannot get dagger to compile when i do so...
i have tried making the injection site as follows:-
@JvmSuppressWildcards
data class FootballLeague<M: Manager> @Inject constructor(val teamMap: Map<@JvmSuppressWildcards Class<M>, Set<Player>>) {

however my code fails to compile with error
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<Manager>,java.util.Set<Player>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

do i have to employ "*", or is there an approach where i can constrain the class type?
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class FootballTeamModule {

    @Provides
    @ElementsIntoSet
    @Named("LiverpoolPlayers")
    fun providesLiverpoolPlayers(mohamedSalah: MohamedSalah, virgilVanDyke: VirgilVanDyke): Set<Player> {
        return HashSet<Player>(listOf(mohamedSalah, virgilVanDyke))
    }

    @Provides
    @ElementsIntoSet
    @Named("ManchesterPlayers")
    fun providesManchesterPlayers(harryMaguire: HarryMaguire, masonMount: MasonMount, casimiro: CarlosCasimiro): Set<Player> {
        return HashSet<Player>(listOf(harryMaguire, masonMount, casimiro))
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(JurgenKlopp::class)
    //@StringKey("JurgenKlopp")
    fun providesLiverpool(@Named("LiverpoolPlayers") players: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards Player>): Set<Player>
    {
        return players
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(ErikTenHag::class)
    //@StringKey("ErikTenHag")
    fun providesManchester(@Named("ManchesterPlayers") players: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards Player>): Set<Player> {
        return players
    }
}

interface Player {
    fun name(): String
    fun wages(): Double
    fun position(): String

}

interface Manager {
    fun name(): String
    fun nationality(): String
}

class MohamedSalah @Inject constructor() : Player {

    override fun name(): String = this::class.java.simpleName

    override fun wages(): Double = 18200000.00

    override fun position(): String = "Forward"

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${name()} - ${wages()} - ${position()}"
    }
}

class VirgilVanDyke @Inject constructor() : Player {

    override fun name(): String = this::class.java.simpleName

    override fun wages(): Double = 11440000.00

    override fun position(): String = "Defender"

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${name()} - ${wages()} - ${position()}"
    }
}

class JurgenKlopp @Inject constructor() : Manager {

    override fun name(): String = this::class.java.simpleName
    override fun nationality(): String = "German"
}

class ErikTenHag @Inject constructor() : Manager {

    override fun name(): String = this::class.java.simpleName
    override fun nationality(): String = "Netherlands"
}

class CarlosCasimiro @Inject constructor() : Player {

    override fun name(): String = this::class.java.simpleName

    override fun wages(): Double = 118200000.00

    override fun position(): String = "Midfield"

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${name()} - ${wages()} - ${position()}"
    }
}

class MasonMount @Inject constructor() : Player {

    override fun name(): String = this::class.java.simpleName

    override fun wages(): Double = 13000000.00

    override fun position(): String = "Midfield"

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${name()} - ${wages()} - ${position()}"
    }
}

class HarryMaguire @Inject constructor() : Player {

    override fun name(): String = this::class.java.simpleName

    override fun wages(): Double = 1.50

    override fun position(): String = "Defender"

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${name()} - ${wages()} - ${position()}"
    }

}

@JvmSuppressWildcards
data class FootballLeague @Inject constructor(val teamMap: Map<@JvmSuppressWildcards Class<*>, Set<Player>>) {
    fun getFootballLeagueInstance() {
        teamMap.entries.forEach {
            println("xxooxx ${it.key} to ${it.value}")
        }

    }
}


First off, let's address the KClass/Class part of the question. Annotations written in Kotlin always use KClass instead of Class, but that's just a language concept made to allow being independent of the JVM. In reality when building for JVM these KClass arguments/parameters are compiled into plain Java Classes. So, Dagger sees them as Class and doesn't know anything about KClass.
Now concerning the Class<*> type constraints. Yes, you can constrain the type inside the Class<>. For that you'll need to declare a custom @MapKey key annotation, like this:
@dagger.MapKey
annotation class ManagerClassKey(
    val value: KClass<out Manager>
)

And then use this new ManagerClassKey instead of ClassKey.
